# Java 8 Optional - should I use it in this example

Tags: java, option-type

After long time on Java 7 I am finally converting to Java 8. I am wondering though whats the best construct in this case: lets go directly to example:

```
class Bar {
    private Foo foo;
    // getters, setters
}

class Foo {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
    private String value3;
    private String value4;
    // getters, setters
}
```

What is the best option(al) for checking whether foo is not null and has at least one value filled?

1.

```
    Optional<Foo> foo = Optional.ofNullable(bar.getFoo());
    if(foo.map(Foo::getValue1).isPresent()
            ||foo.map(Foo::getValue2).isPresent()
            ||foo.map(Foo::getValue3).isPresent()
            ||foo.map(Foo::getValue4).isPresent()){


    }
```

2.

```
    Optional<Foo> foo = Optional.ofNullable(bar.getFoo());
    if(foo.filter(foo->foo.getValue1()!=null
    ||foo.getValue2()!=null
    ||foo.getValue3()!=null
    ||foo.getValue4()!=null).isPresent()){

    }
```

3. or just use old good nullchecks

```
    Foo foo1=bar.getFoo();
    if(foo1!=null&&(foo.getValue1()!=null
    ||foo.getValue2()!=null
    ||foo.getValue3()!=null
    ||foo.getValue4()!=null)){

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: 3. Optional is not meant to replace null checks. It's meant to be used as a method return type to signal that the method might return an "absent" value.

Comment: ok, thanks, because I was reading https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional and the examples suggested it could be used like this.

Comment: In this case, use #3.  Optional can be used in other locations than just return types, such as variables and fields, and it is definitely intended for use on formal parameters.  Here is a discussion I wrote on [when to use Optional](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/nothing-is-better-than-optional.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you mernst.